# How to customize the HTML output of radio buttons on ZF2?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2, zend-form

I want to customize the HTML output of radio buttons on Zend Framework 2. I'm using the class `Zend\Form\Fieldset`

In my Fieldset class is like this:

```
$this->add(array( 
    'name' => 'type', 
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio', 
    'attributes' => array(
        'value' => $this->getType(),
    ), 
    'options' => array( 
        'label' => 'Type',
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class' => '',
        ),
        'value_options' => array(
            '1' => 'Option 1',
            '2' => 'Option 2',
            '3' => 'Option 3'
        ),
    ),
));
```

In my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <?php echo $this->formRadio($form->get('type')) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it is printing like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="1" checked="checked">Option 1
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="2">Option 2
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="3">Option 3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I want it to prints like below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <p>
            <input name="type" type="radio" id="option1" />
            <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="type" type="radio" id="option2" />
            <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="type" type="radio" id="option3" />
            <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to change because I'm using MaterializeCSS for my layout and it works only this way, I think.

**UPDATE**

My solution was:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <?php $element = $form->get('type') ?>
        <?php foreach ($element->getValueOptions() as $value => $label): ?>
            <?php $checked = $value == $element->getValue() ? 'checked="true"' : ''; ?>
            <p>
                <input name="<?php echo $element->getName() ?>" type="radio" id="<?php echo $element->getName().$value ?>" value="<?php echo $value ?>" <?php echo $checked ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo $element->getName().$value ?>"><?php echo $label ?></label>
            </p>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like different rendering of your form elements, you should call them sepperatly.

Take a look at http://zf2cheatsheet.com/#form and scroll down for a list of helpers

Comment: zf docs sucks so much it even need cheatsheets from third parties... :-(

Comment: No need a cheatsheet, just read the code from the framework, really not that special